# Creating child processes/killing processes in C/UNIX

Tags: c, unix, operating-system, process

So I've been working on this today and I'm pretty sure I'm close, but I'm still a bit confused on how to terminate child processes and if I'm doing this assignment correctly. Here's the problem description:

```
Write a UNIX program that creates a child process that 
prints a greeting, sleeps for 20 seconds, then exits.
The parent process should print a greeting before creating 
the child, and another after the child has terminated. It 
should then terminate.
```

And here's the code that I have:

```
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main()
{
    int child;

    printf("Parent Greeting\n");
    child = fork();
    if(child >= 0)
    {
        if(child == 0)
        {
            printf("Child process\n");
            sleep(2);
            printf("Child exiting\n");
            exit(0);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Failed\n");
    }
    printf("End");
    exit(1);
    return 0;
}
```

The issue I'm running into is how to properly terminate the child process. If I have the exit statements commented out, then the child will run, wait, and then the "End" statement will print. If I have the exit statements in, then the child process will say that it's exiting and the program will just sit until I ctrl+c out of it. Any help would be appreciated, as I'm interested in the topic but am a bit confused :) Thank you!

Comment: I waited for 2 using sleep(2) while writing it so that I'm not sitting for 20 seconds waiting for it to do its job.

Comment: You are basically looking to make an orphan process, right?

Comment: After sleeping is done it should end itself, I don't think that there is any need for exit() statement. Also, you can remove the code of the child from inside the parent's if condition. That might help. Again, I have not tried it out so cannot be 100% sure but it might work.

Comment: Your program is exiting right away, because the parent doesn't wait for the child to exit. You're probably not noticing that `End` is being printed immediately, with no newline between it and the shell prompt.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't have to terminate the child process from the parent; it should terminate itself (and does after the `sleep()`, `printf()` and `exit()`). The parent process should [`wait()` or `waitpid()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/wait.html) for the child to die before it prints the `"End"` message.  Also, your `"End\n"` message should include a newline.

The `exit(1);` (at the end of the first program) is not wanted; it indicates failure.  The `exit()` function does not return, so as written the `return` is redundant.  But it would be better to remove the `exit()` and leave the `return 0;` indicating success.

(Note that the child should include a call to `exit()`, probably with the value 0 rather than 1 as in the revised code.  After all, it has done its job successfully.)

Comment: Even though `return 0;` is equivalent to `exit(0);` in the main function, isn't the latter the preferred convention?

Comment: @Barmar: I strongly prefer `return` over `exit()` at the end of `main()`.  The `main()` function is a function that returns a value.  In the code I work on, I carefully ensure that programs that end with `exit(0);` are revised to use `return` instead.  And it also shuts up compilation warnings with some compilers, and it side-tracks the `void main()` non-option (you can't return 0 from a function declared to return `void`)!

Comment: Thank you! I had to do some looking around for how to use wait, but I think I got it now. I did have to include an exit in the child if-statement, because otherwise it would print "end" twice.

Comment: Absolutely; the `exit()` in the child paragraph is correct — and was not the subject of my diatribe.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have forced the parent process to exit before the child process , in that case the child process ceases to become a zombie process and in some time a ghost process , add a wait() at the end before the final exit .

Comment: Actually, if a process's parent process dies without waiting, then a system process (normally `init`, PID 1) inherits the orphan and waits for it to die.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is exactly what you wanted to achieve.

```
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

void err_sys(const char* x)
{
    perror(x);
    exit(1);
}


int main()
{
        pid_t childPid;
        printf("Parent greeting\n");
        childPid =fork();
        if (childPid  >=0)
        {
                if(childPid == 0)
                {
                        printf("Child process\n");
                        sleep(20);
                        printf("child exiting\n");
                   }
                else
                {
                     waitpid(-1,NULL,0);
                }

        }
        else
            {
                     err_sys("fork error\n");
            }
        printf("END\n");
        return 0;
}
```